# Weighted sum of matrices in Tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I have a 3-dimensional tensor A of size (M,N,N) and an 1 dimensional tensor p of size M. I want to compute the weighted sum of matrices:

[image]

In NumPy I am implementing the following code:

```
import numpy as np
temp=np.array([p[m]*A[m] for m in range(M)])
B=sum(temp);
```

I want to do the same in TensorFlow but I don't seem to find any inbuilt operations to carry out the same. I tried `tf.matmul` and `tf.mul` but they don't seem to be giving the desired result. Can someone suggest me a right way to do this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

well it seems it's quite easy to do with explicit broadcasting. But I'm not sure how efficient is this!

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[1, 7],
              [4, 4]],
             [[2, 6],
              [5, 3]],
             [[3, 5],
              [6, 2]]])

p = np.array([4,3,2])

M = 3
N = 2

#numpy version
temp=np.array([p[m]*A[m] for m in range(M)])
B=sum(temp);

#tensorflow version
import tensorflow as tf
A_tf = tf.constant(A,dtype=tf.float64)
p_tf = tf.constant(p,dtype=tf.float64)
p_tf_broadcasted = tf.tile(tf.reshape(p_tf,[M,1,1]), tf.pack([1,N,N]))
B_tf = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(A_tf,p_tf_broadcasted), axis=0)

sess=tf.Session()
B_tf_ = sess.run(B_tf)


#make sure they're equal
B_tf_ == B


#array([[ True,  True],
#       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a vectorized version of the above? I have a `P` matrix of size `(K,M)` and a tensor `A` of size `(M,N,N)`. I want to compute a tensor `B` of size `(K,N,N)` where `B[k]=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} P[k][m] A_m `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute a tensor B of size `(K,N,N)` when you have a P matrix of size `(K,M)` and a tensor A of size `(M,N,N)`, you can follow it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

K = 2
M = 3
N = 2

np.random.seed(0)
A = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,5,(M,N,N)),dtype=tf.float64)

# when K.shape=(K,M)
P = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,5,(K,M)),dtype=tf.float64)
# when K.shape=(M,)
# P = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,5,(M,)),dtype=tf.float64)

P_new = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(P,-1),-1)

# if K.shape=(K,M) set axis=1,if K.shape=(M,) set axis=0,
B = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(P_new , A),axis=1)

with tf.Session()as sess:
    print(sess.run(P))
    print(sess.run(A))
    print(sess.run(B))

[[1. 4. 3.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
[[[1. 4.]
  [2. 1.]]

 [[4. 4.]
  [4. 4.]]

 [[2. 4.]
  [2. 3.]]]
[[[23. 32.]
  [24. 26.]]

 [[ 7. 12.]
  [ 8.  8.]]]
```

The above code can be modified to include the solution of problem in your question.